# existing umbraco cms set up in local server

Tags: asp.net, web-config, localhost, content-management-system, umbraco

I am completely new with the umbraco CMS and one of my client want to make some changes on his umbraco CMS web site. So i have downloaded the umbraco CMS projects files and database from the server and i need to configure it on my local server. I am using windows 10 OS. I can install a fresh umbraco cms in the local server. But When i try to run the existing in local server, its asking me for install the fresh umbraco CMS.Can anyone help me on sort out this issue?

Note : I don't have changed the any configurations on the files. Just simply running the project with Microsoft WebMatrix app. Please help me with the database and other configuration settings also.

Aby help will be really appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the Umbraco installation is assuming it is a new installation and then creates a new database for you.

You need to download the website files directly from the server and place those in a folder which can be served by a webserver on your local machine. Then you need to get a backup of the database on the server and restore this on a SQL server on your local machine.

When this is done, you need to make sure the connectionstring in the `web.config` of the site is set up correct to match where you have restored the database on your local SQL server. Search for `umbracoDbDsn` and make sure the server name, credentials and database name is correct.

When this is done, you should be able to start up the site and hopefully it will run just as it did on the server.